# Django AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'select'

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgis, geodjango

I've got a GeoDjango instance connected to a PostGIS database backend. When I query a table in this database, I get the error in the title:

```
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'select'
```

As suggested elsewhere, I checked to make sure that my `local_settings.py` file specified the correct database engine: `'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'`. This is already correct in my settings file.

How do you fix this problem?

Comment: It sounds as if the engine is not `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'` despite what you say about local settings, but yo haven’t included enough information to tell why that is the case.

Answer (score 33):

It sounds as though your Django settings aren't quite right and that your database `ENGINE` may be `'django.db.backends.postgresql'`, when it should be `'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis'`. To confirm, run:

```
python manage.py shell

>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.DATABASES
{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
  'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
  'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
  'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
  'HOST': '',
  'NAME': 'mydatabase',
  'OPTIONS': {},
  'PASSWORD': '',
  'PORT': '',
  'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIRROR': None, 'NAME': None},
  'TIME_ZONE': None,
  'USER': ''}}
```

The above shows that I have one `'default'` database configured and it's using the "postgis" engine (which is what we want).

Watch out for the use of the `dj_database_url` package in your settings as this may be overriding the database settings from environment variables. Also watch for multiple databases other than "default" in the settings.

Comment: Great explanation ✌

Answer (score 0):

Check if you forgot to add,

```
'django.contrib.gis',
```

inside your `INSTALLED_APPS`